# Softeners for conversational topic transitions: "Well, …", "So, …"

Tags: word-choice, spoken-language, conversational

In conversation, we often introduce a new topic or make a transition with a little introductory word, like "Well, …" or "So, …" in English or "Allora …" in Italian. For example, if previously we've talked about meeting somewhere, but that topic has been brushed aside for a while, I might bring it up like this:

> **So,** where would you like to meet?
>
> **Well,** where would you like to meet?

The little introductory word softens the transition to the new topic. Omitting it would make the sentence seem abrupt or officious. Even at the start of a conversation, these softeners are often appropriate.

How do you make the corresponding softening in conversational Latin? With *autem* or *enim* or some related word? Or does one not do this in Latin?

Comment: I don't know if it counts, but there is a lot of [_enim_](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/vulsearch?searchtext=enim) and [_autem_](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/vulsearch?searchtext=autem) working as connectors (as the *second* word in the sentence) in the Vulgate. _Autem_ is adversative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that ***nam*** can be used like this, ["to resume the course of thought after a parenthetical interruption".](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=nam&la=la#Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=nam-contents)

In practice, however, it was hard to find examples that actually capture the full sense of "so, as I was saying/to get back to the matter at hand".  Instead, *nam* is more often used (even in the examples cited by Lewis and Short) to say something more like "so, because of what I just said, this follows".

Nevertheless, here are the examples I thought best illustrated what you're after:

> ***nam***, simulac me Dyrrhachium attigisse audivit ...
>
> **so, as I was saying**, as soon as he heard that I had reached
>   Dyrrhachium ...

Cicero, *Pro Plancio*, 41.98

> ***nam*** **et** ipse vobis rem horribilem narrabo
>
> **well/and so**, I'm going to tell you something horrible myself

Petronius, *Satyricon*, 63

> ***nam*** meus pater intus nunc est eccum Iuppiter
>
> **well**, look, my father Jupiter is inside now!

Plautus, *Amphitryon*, 120

Answer (score 2):

***Porro*** ([Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DP%3Aentry%20group%3D77%3Aentry%3Dporro))

**I  Literally**  straight on, directly

**II Transf.**

> **2.** In partic., in discourse. a. In the progress of an argument, or in a sequence of ideas, then, next, furthermore, moreover, besides:

*'Porro,'* is used twice at the beginning of a sentence in that sense in the [CCC ms](http://image.ox.ac.uk/images/corpus/ms122/f5v.jpg) which gives instructions for *'Alea Evangelii,'*  linked to the Google page.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "corresponding softening" is a more informal parlance, because you don't really see that in written Latin text.  If you were just speaking Latin aloud, then, yes, I would probably use "enim."

Comment: A great many written Latin texts are anything *but* formal! Do you have any reason for suggesting *enim*?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on what I would do in Latin, not on any rule I know.

It depends on context.
If you have both been silent for a while, then the introductory word indicates that you are about to say something; without it the other party is likely to miss your first actual word.
To this end, I often start simply with a "hmm...".
If you want something more formal, I would remind of the topic:
"De conventu illo: Quando tibi placeat convenire?"
In my experience and knowledge (which are both admittedly limited!), Latin does not have proper softener words for this kind of thing, and I don't think anything could match the English "so" or "well" in tone.

If you want to wrap up the conversation you've just had, the situation is a bit different.
Consider: "So, we'll meet at the graveyard gate at midnight?"
In this use I would go with "ita" or "itaque" or nothing at all.
I have nothing to support "ita(que)" other than my own idiosyncrasy.

I feel I should read some Plautus for insights into conversational sentence structures.
Although I haven't had the chance to do so in proper detail, I dare recommend taking a look.
My quick impression that there are few if any such softeners.

Comment: I'm actually pretty sure that *ita* can't be used in this way. You'd get my upvote if you can find an example though!

Comment: @brianpck Well, I can use it in this way. :) I couldn't find any examples of anything (my personal Latin correspondence won't count), so the idiomatic thing seems to be to say nothing. The suggested word is nothing but a personal preference. I clarified the answer a little regarding that point. I'll add more if I find something, but my hopes aren't high.

Comment: I'm going with _Et ubi convenire vis?_ in the text message I'm about to send, unless someone tells me that's wrong _quam primum._ :)

Comment: @BenKovitz I won't oppose to *et* here. I have a feeling that the Romans did have some introductory or softening sounds, but perhaps not proper words (like my *hmm...*) and therefore not indicated in writing. (I'd be happy if there was any evidence regarding these aspects of classical speech.)