# Was deliberately bad grammar ever used for emphasis in Latin?

Tags: example-request

In English, we can sometimes use deliberately incorrect grammar for effect in speech. The first example that comes to mind is a more colloquial example:

> I ain't never going to do...

When I hear this sentence and the double-negative, it that implies that the speaker is more emphatically saying they aren't going to do whatever it is they aren't going to do (with a bit of added attitude).

Are there any examples in Latin where something that should be incorrect grammar was allowed? It's okay if it's was considered a regional or colloquial usage as long as it would have still be viewed as technically incorrect. There is a similar question asking about [known speech errors](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5623/speech-errors-in-ancient-rome), although I'm looking more for examples where it was viewed as acceptable to use by some.

Comment: I think that a pluperfect ending can be reduplicated to make a plupluperfect. I don't know if that counts as 'deliberately bad grammar' though.

Comment: There's a word for deliberate faults of scansion (or in popular verse of rhythm) to add significance. (The only example I can quote is 13th C.)  I'll try and find it, if it would be useful.